# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'TIDAS.DLL' (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, dll

I get the error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'TIDAS.DLL':
>   The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

I keep getting that runtime error.
But I have all the files that goes with that `.DLL`.

I have a solution that someone else made and it works fine.
But my solution... I keep getting this error and I do not know why...

I am writing this program in C#.
I have all the same `.DLL`s like in the other solution...

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you try just to search on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+System.DLLNotFoundException+) the same issues?

Comment: yes I did but I did not see anything that would help